# How to split a column in R based upon how many characters there are in each element?

Tags: r

I have a column in my data named Sex/neuter status. The values that may appear are male, male entire, male neutered. I would like to create another column to separate this into column 1: sex and column 2: neuter status. For each case I would like the sex to appear in column 1 and its neuter status to appear in column 2. There will be some neuter status' missing for some cases but each case will have sex recorded.

Example data:

```
Data = data.frame(CaseID = c('1','2','3','4','5'), sexneuterstatus =c('male','maleneutered','maleentire','male','maleneutered'))
```

I have tried to use the split function but have had no luck.

I assume i need to split the column based on the number of characters, i.e., if there are 2 this means neuter status is present so send the second value (neuter status) to a new column. However, i dont know how I would do this.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate` with a regex look behind, this assumes that male always precedes the neuter status in the original data frame and that male is the only gender, i.e. no cases of female.

```r
library(tidyr)

Data = data.frame(CaseID = c('1','2','3','4','5'), sexneuterstatus =c('male','maleneutered','maleentire','male','maleneutered'))

df_new <- 
  Data |> 
  separate(col = sexneuterstatus, into = c("sex", "status"), sep = "(?<=male)")

df_new

#>   CaseID  sex   status
#> 1      1 male         
#> 2      2 male neutered
#> 3      3 male   entire
#> 4      4 male         
#> 5      5 male neutered
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I got the following message: Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 500 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].  And it printed the expected result but when I view the column in the whole dataset, nothing has been changed. How do I ensure the changes have been made? Many thanks

Comment: @at12342012, check out the updated answer; it may be that the new data frame has not been assigned to a new object?

Comment: thank you again. It hasnt worked for me, it put in the new columns but all of the values in the neuter status column are NA and the sex column contains the same values as the original sexneuterstatus column

Comment: That is very odd, does this happen with the dataset in the question?

Comment: Yes, I also get the following error message when I try to run anything:  Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name

Comment: Oh dear, this is all a bit beyond me - time to close the application, possibly the computer, have a cup of tea and start afresh! There may be issues relating to the version of R and possibly R studio and tidyr you are using. It works fine on my set up.